# Unable to set document domain to amazonaws on firefox 24

Tags: security, firefox, amazon-web-services, cross-domain, document

Its a very common practice to set the document.domain to superdomain for allowing cross-subdomain calls. It used to work until firefox 23 but I am facing this issue after upgrading to firefox 24.

When my url is say -  def.abc.mycompany.com

```
document.domain = "mycompany.com"  - WORKS
document.domain = "abc.mycompany.com"  - WORKS
```

def.abc.mycompany.com is basically an alias to ec2-123-345-2678-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com, but when I do it on the same server

```
document.domain = "amazonaws.com"   - ERROR
document.domain = "compute-1.amazonaws.com " - ERROR
```

It throws - **NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_DOCUMENT_DOMAIN: Illegal document.domain value**

Is anyone else experiencing the same issue on FF-24? Did they disable setting document domain to any cloud provider's? I don't see this on Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

amazonws.com is not a super-domain of def.abc.mycompany.com. Server aliasas (CNAMEs etc) don't matter in terms of web same-origin security.

If you were loading from ec2-123-345-2678-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com you could probably set the domain to amazonws.com, but that's also a terrible idea because anyone hosting on amazonws.com would become same-origin as you and could steal data.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the 
amazonaws.com
compute-1.amazonaws.com
is added in a list of top level domain.
Check this:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List